# How to find the exact match using GREP

Tags: regex, bash, grep

HI I have a fairly big Log File and want to see which sort of website being requested. 
For that I am using grep expression

```
grep -o 'http://[a-ZA-Z.-]*/' text.log
```

It gives all the urls in the documents. I want to get the only urls that look like this 
`http://url/` 
URLs like this `http://url/somethingAfterslash` should not be the part of output.

Comment: log files lines are generally organised with fields delimited by tabs (or an other character), so the urls are probably always in the same col, using awk (or cut) will be more easy.

Comment: You can try: `grep -oE 'http://[a-zA-Z.-]+/[[:blank:]]' text.log`

Comment: @anubhava isn't `[a-Z]` invalid range?

Comment: Of course it is :) I just copied that part from OP. (Fixed now)

Comment: Thanks alot @anubhava it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a single string, so you may expect it to be separated from the rest by *whitespaces* (this is a technical term in regular expression; see below). I would try with

`grep -o 'http://[a-zA-Z.-]*/[[:space:]]' text.log`

this matches any whitespace at the end of the word, but also tab and newlines.

In addition, some URL may contain digits or underscores, so you may have to further tune your pattern a bit more. To include these two

`grep -o 'http://[0-9a-zA-Z.-_]*/[[:space:]]' text.log`